# Get first 9 elements from Google RSS feed xml in PHP

Tags: php, xml, foreach, rss, google-feed-api

I'm currently working with Google RSS feeds. I received this XML response.

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<generator>NFE/1.0</generator>
<title>blockchain - Google News</title>
<link>...</link>
<language>en</language>
<webMaster>news-feedback@google.com</webMaster>
<copyright>&copy;2017 Google</copyright>
<pubDate>Fri, 17 Nov 2017 09:41:26 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 17 Nov 2017 09:41:26 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<image>...</image>
<description>Google News</description>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I'm using this `foreach()` to loop through all items:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/q/blockchain/blockchain?ned=us&hl=en&gl=US');

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo $item->title."<br/>";
    echo $item->link."<br/>";
    echo $item->pubDate."<br/>";
}
```

But this foreach returns me all items.

How can I get only first 9 items from this XML?

Comment: Google updated their news feed because before you were able to add a num=9 param to the URL to limit the results. However since the upgrade this param doesn't work so it could be under construction or deprecated.

Comment: Yeah I know. Thats why I'm finding the hardocoded way to use it. As I really need it on my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Easy and quick fix:-***

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
  if($i<9){
    echo $item->title."<br/>";
    echo $item->link."<br/>";
    echo $item->pubDate."<br/>";
  }
 $i++;
}
```

***Better solution is:***-

```
$array = array_slice($rss->channel->item,0,9);

foreach ($array as $item) {
  echo $item->title."<br/>";
  echo $item->link."<br/>";
  echo $item->pubDate."<br/>";
}
```

Reference:- [PHP manual: array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 2):

Well I found the answer:

```
   $i = 0;

   foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
      $i++;

      echo $item->title."<br/>";
      echo $item->link."<br/>";
      echo $item->pubDate."<br/>";


      if($i == 10) break;
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, it works as well. Thank you bro for a simple idea! Works perfect!